# "Авторизация заблокирована" - можно ли сказать то же самое короче?

Tags: одним-словом

Как можно укоротить сообщение:

> "**Авторизация заблокирована** Пожалуйста, подождите 60 секунд"

так, чтобы сохранился смысл и "уважение" к читающему ?

Во всех вариантах, которые я мог придумать, исчезает важная информация, которая присутствует в каждом слове исходного.

Например, слово **Авторизация** можно заменить на **Вход**, но вход куда ?

Например **блокировать** можно заменить на **запрещён**, но не значит ли это, что навсегда ?

Comment: Можете раскрыть свой вопрос.
Вы ищете аналог выражения "Авторизация заблокирована" или вы ищете фразу типа "Эх, вот незадача"  - но тогда это вопрос не про русский язык. Главная задача этого сервиса - отвечать на вопросы про русский язык, а помощь в поиске правильных формулировок - это, увы, немного про другое.

Comment: А как и где можно найти правильную короткую формулировку ? Я нашёл этот замечательный форум и решил, что тут начитанные люди могут дать хоть один два варианта правильной формулировки.

Comment: спаcибо, что отредактировали. Как по мне - всё равно на грани оффтопа, но пусть комьюнити решает  )

Comment: Возможно, но в данном вопросе интересует возможность русского языка сжимать предложения без использования сокращений на столько сильно, как можно.

Comment: Это сложная фраза, выражающая сложную мысль. Её нельзя значительно укоротить без потери смысла.

Comment: Неужели вообще никак ? Кроме того, что предложил @alex still.

Comment: "чтобы сохранился смысл и "уважение" к читающему" - смотря кто читает. Для кого-то и слово "авторизация" будет наездом, потому что заумное и непонятное.

Comment: "В данном вопросе интересует возможность русского языка сжимать предложения без использования сокращений на столько сильно, как можно" - ИМХО такая возможность в русском языке очень нерегулярна. Иногда удаётся найти хорошую краткую форму, но как правило - не рассчитывайте на это.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Доступ закрыт" по смысловой нагрузке тоже подойдет и короче чем "Авторизация заблокирована".

Comment: Хм. Как вариант ! Например, "**Доступ закрыт на 60 секунд**", но куда тогда деть "Пожалуйста" ?

Comment: @V.7 никуд. "Доступ закрыт на 60 секунд" и достаточно.

Comment: Не кажется ли агрессивным ?

Comment: Не, и без пожалуйста в варианте с "на 60 секунд" звучит довольно мягко.

Comment: "Доступ закрыт, подождите пожалуйста." - а вместо статического текста "60 секунда" поставить "живой" счетчик (уменьшающаяся полоса, например, или цифры обратного отсчета).

Comment: Либо "позитивное мышление" - "Доступ будет разрешён через 60 секунд"

Comment: На мой взгляд, выбор подходящего варианта зависит как от тематики сайта, так и от характера его аудитории. Ресурс, подающий себя неформально, может позволить себе многие вольности, например, "Входа нет", "Посторонним В.", "Перезвоните через минуту", "Занято, подождите" и тому подобное, особенно если текст согласуется с его тематикой. Ясно, что для "серьезной" страницы это неуместно. Что касается "вежливости", то в данном случае мы имеем дело с нейтральным информативным сообщением вроде "Магазин не работает", поэтому "Доступ закрыт" подходит очень хорошо.